# Circular dependency in React JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, circular-dependency

I am having an issue with React creating a circular structure in an object I am passing as a prop. Basically, I am using `react-bootstrap-table2` to render a table of data. This component requires two arrays of objects as props: `columns` and `data`. I am creating and passing these props, but for some reason they contain a circular structure. At some point, `JSON.stringify` is called and `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` is thrown. The example below shows the problem occurring in the `columns` prop. I create a hard-coded array and one dynamically to showcase the difference. `this.props.cols = ["2017","2018","2019"]`

```
const columns1 = [
    {
        dataField: 'dataTopic',
        text: null
    },
    {
        dataField: '2017',
        text: 
            <div>
                <div>2016 – 2017</div>
            </div>
    },
    {
        dataField: '2018',
        text:
            <div>
                <div>2017 – 2018</div>
            </div>
    },
    {
        dataField: '2019',
        text:
            <div>
                <div>2018 – 2019</div>
            </div>
    }
];

class MyTable extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        cols: PropTypes.array
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.getColumns = this.getColumns.bind(this);
        this.getRows = this.getRows.bind(this);
    }

    getColumns() {
        const columns = [
            {
                dataField: 'dataTopic',
                text: null
            }
        ];

        this.props.cols.forEach((year) => {
            columns.push(           
                {
                    dataField: year,
                    text: 
                        <div>
                            <div>{year - 1} – {year}</div>
                        </div>
                }
            );
        });

        return columns;
    }

    getRows(){
        //Do stuff
    }

    render() {
        console.log(columns1);
        console.log(this.getColumns());

        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable keyField='dataTopic' columns={this.getColumns()} data={this.getRows()} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyTable;
```

I get the following output to the console:

[image: console.log]

For some reason, everything is the same except for the `_owner` attribute in the JSX element. If I expand `_owner`, I find where my recursion is occurring:

[image: owner recursion]

I understand that `_owner` is used to track the parent of a React component, but I don't understand why it is null in `columns1` and not in the object returned by `getColumns()`. Could someone please explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 2):

The `_owner` is `null` for `columns1` because this array has been declared outside of the `MyTable` component.

Comment: I had considered that already and tried moving the getColumns function outside of the class declaration and passing in the `cols` array as a parameter, but it still outputs to the console with the _owner attribute.

Comment: This method is still called by `MyTable`.

Comment: But the real problem here is that you are trying to serialize something that should actually be rendered. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: What I am trying to render is the bootstrap table component, in order to do that I have to pass in the columns as an array of objects. I found that you can include a JSX element as a value for the `text` key, which allows me to customize the look and functionality of each cell in the table.

Comment: Sure. But that is not the problem. The problem is that you are trying to store this array. The exception is happening in `Store.set`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. I am still relatively new to React. Could you go into more detail?

Comment: Check the stacktrace of the exception. The problem occurs because the array is stringified because it should be stored somewhere. This is NOT standard React behavior, so I can't say any more about that.

Comment: `store.set` is being called in the bootstrap component which I don't have control over. That function calls `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((data))`, but because data contains the circular structure, it throws an exception. So in order to get around it, I am trying to get rid of the circular structure.

Comment: I get that `_owner` is being set because I am calling it the function in the MyTable component, but how else am I supposed to create the array of objects from the `props`?

Comment: Wrong approach, I would say. They are trying to achieve something with that code and I would say that passing React components as the text property is not supported and only works by accident

Comment: Yeah, after digging more into it I see that you are right. I also found that the table component I am using does provide functionality for cell formatting, but I didn't pursue that approach because I thought I could submit JSX no problem.